# How to hide that i am using selenium to browse

Tags: python, selenium

I am trying to scrape some information from a website. When I enter it using my browser (manually), everything works well and I don't get any request to solve Google captcha. But when I enter it using selenium library, the website starts to show the captcha.

How can I hide from websites that I am using selenium?

Why the captcha appears only when I use selenium library?

Comment: The captcha is to try to prevent automation. In your code, at the point right where the captcha is displayed (e.g. after doing `driver.get(url)`), add an `input('pausing for captcha ...')` statement so that you can enter the captcha manually after which you can then respond to the `input` statement to continue execution.

Comment: @booboo and it won't apear if I reload the page, or if I go to the next page?

Comment: I don't know for sure; you will have to try it.

Comment: @Booboo .. I am .. it seems that it works :D

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/q/33225947/6793637